# How to get list of only email Items from Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In Google Forms, we can set an `Item` as `required` and add validation to accept email input for this item.

Now I need to find a way to get ***only*** those email fields

This is my implementation at the moment:

```
const items = FormApp.getActiveForm().getItems()
  return items
    .filter(item => !!(item.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.TEXT && item.asTextItem().isRequired()))
    .map(item => ({
      id: item.getId(),
      title: item.getTitle(),
    }))
```

As you can see, this can only check if the `Item` is `text field` and `is required`.

How to check if the Item is email address?

---

**EDIT**: I use this boilerplate to add support for ES6 and React syntax that you see in the code:

https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions by default. What are you using to make them work in your project?

Comment: @Rubén: I use this boilerplate https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script. Although it has some issues but I think React + ES6 feature is pretty good for development

Comment: I think that you should add that to the question.

Comment: @Rubén: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `setValidation` but there isn't a `getValidation`. Go to the Google Apps Script Issue tracker to search for a feature request to add it. If you found it, starred it but if there isn't post one.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features